# Hide/disable tooltips chart.js

Tags: html5-canvas, chart.js

I'm trying to hide the tooltips in a line chart using chart.js.

I have tried this code, but they never hide.

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipenabled = false;
```

You can see all the code here of the chart:

https://jsfiddle.net/w6zs07xx/
Thanks!

Comment: after checking your jsfiddle i found that you are using old version of chart.js file in which there was a bug regarding TOOLTIP that why it's not hiding that. (Reference site : https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/494)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

To turn off for a specific chart instead of in global defaults use this in the options object. Using v2.5.0

```
options: {
    tooltips: {
         enabled: false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! finally, someone that doesn't mutate the global configuration.

Answer (score 41):

For v4.4.1

```json
options: {
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }
}
```

Docs - https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html

Answer (score 16):

For me `showTooltips = false` didn't work.

My solution was:

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.enabled = false;
```

My version is:

`2.1.4`

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: This is still the correct solution in version `2.5.0`

Comment: Works on `2.5.0` but unfortunately can't get it working for a specific only chart.

Answer (score 8):

You have the wrong property name. It should be

```
Chart.defaults.global.showTooltips = false;
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0tfvnmx1/

Answer (score 8):

For v2.9.3:

```
options: {
    tooltips: false
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For 3+ the path is `options.plugin.tooltip.enabled`.

Answer (score 4):

use the following option for hide the tooltip

```
 tooltips :{
                custom : function(tooltipModel) 
                 {
                  tooltipModel.opacity = 0;
                 }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked.

Using Chart JS version 4.1.1

```
Chart.defaults.plugins.tooltip.enabled = false;
```